# AutoCompleteTextView not getting device emails in ِa Login Activity

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to do login process using personal email, and to make the application more simple i'am trying to show the logged in emails to the user to make him chooses between them.
Using exist "Login Activity" in Android Studio, all code and permissions be fine but onLoadFinished method still returned with empty array.
can any one help me in this problem?

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Code:

```
private void populateAutoComplete() {
        if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("grantedPermission", "1");
                populateAutoComplete();
            } else{
                Log.d("grantedPermission", "0");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst(); // Here the cursor return empty list (not null)
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
            Log.d("email", cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS)); // not called
        }
        Log.d("emailCount", emails.size() + "");
        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

        mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }
```

Log Statements:

```
12-04 16:31:48.512 10573-10573/com.example.test.testlogin D/grantedPermission: 1
12-04 16:32:05.231 10573-10573/com.example.test.testlogin D/emailCount: 0
```

Comment: Add some log statements to your code. Figure out where it's not getting data

Comment: please, check the update.

Comment: Still not seeing any log statements

Comment: sorry, these logs are enough to you?

Comment: Put one into `onRequestPermissionsResult`. For example, how do are you checking `if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)` works?

Comment: i add what you ask, put the permission its work fine.

Comment: Okay, so now I think that the query for `ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +" = ?"`  is filtering out all the rows, and you get an empty cursor